# Show that $\mathbb{Z}'_\mathbb{C}$ is not a finitely generated $\mathbb{Z}$-module.

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules, finitely-generated

Let $\mathbb{Z}\subset \mathbb{C}$ an extension and $\mathbb{Z}'_\mathbb{C}$ the integral closure of $\mathbb{Z}$ in $\mathbb{C}$.

Show that $\mathbb{Z}'_\mathbb{C}$ is not a finitely generated $\mathbb{Z}$-module.

Comment: Use the fact that a finite extension $k/\mathbb{Q}$ only contains finitely many roots of unity.

Comment: If $\mathbb{Z}'_\mathbb{C}$ is f.g. then (since it is torsion-free) it is free (of finite rank). (I think this is the part you missed.) But it has submodules of arbitrary large rank.

Answer (score 2):

$\mathbb{Z}'_\mathbb{C}$ in particular would have to contain all the roots of unity, and so contain $\Bbb Z[\zeta_n]$ so the number of generators is greater than $\phi(n)$ for all $n$, which of course is impossible as $\phi(n)\to\infty$ as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: Your proof is similar with the fact that the field of algebraic numbers has degree $\infty$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. I  don't understand why a module with a submodule which isn't finitely generated isn't finitely generated, too.

Comment: @PregatireMatematica Every subgroup of $\Bbb Z^m$ is finitely generated, so every subgroup of a finite Abelian group is finitely generated.

Comment: @PregatireMatematica an alternate phrasing (but same substance) that might help you more easily see the situation if $\Bbb Z_{\Bbb C}$ is finitely generated then there are $\alpha_1,\ldots, \alpha_n$ so that $\zeta_m = \sum a_i\alpha_i$. But then that means that $\Bbb Z[\zeta_m]\subseteq\Bbb Z[\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n]$ for all $m$, and clearly the latter has degree bounded by $\prod [\Bbb Z[\alpha_i]:\Bbb Z]<\infty$

Answer (score 1):

More-or-less the same idea as Adam Hughes.

$\mathbb{Z}'_\mathbb{C}$ contains $\Bbb Z[2^{1/n}]$ for all $n\in\Bbb N$. This has rank $n$ (ultimately down to Eisenstein's criterion), so the rank of $\mathbb{Z}'_\mathbb{C}$ must be infinite.